# Group array with groupBy

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, ionic-framework, mapreduce

I am grouping my array using this function:

```
Array.prototype.groupBy = function(prop) {
          return this.reduce(function(groups, item) {
            var val = item[prop];
            groups[val] = groups[val] || [];
            groups[val].push(item);
            return groups;
          }, {});
        }
```

I use it in another function where I get the date

```
    vm.parkings.forEach(function(value, key) {
        value.receiptsByDate = [];
        if (value.receipts != undefined) {
            value.receipts.forEach(function(rcpts) {
                    var date = rcpts.date.split('/');
                    var newDate = date[2] + '/' + date[0];
                    var year = date[2];
                    var month = date[0];
                    var price = rcpts.value;
                    value.receiptsByDate.push({newDate, price, month, year});
                    value.newReceipt = value.receiptsByDate.groupBy('month');
            })
        }
    })
```

Result:

[image: Result]

In my newReceipt I have the objects sorted by month, ok.

I would like to sum the prices according to the month.
Example: inside array three, access the objects and sum the prices.

Is this the best way to do it?

**EDIT**

I've used the underscore and it's working. It looks like this:

```
var result = _.groupBy(receiptsByDate, "month");
var out = _(result).map(function(g, key) {
    return {month: key, price: _(g).reduce(function(m, x){return m + x.price}, 0)}
})
```

Comment: Consider using lodash (lodash.com) to do algorithms

Comment: I'll try to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [linq.js](https://linqjs.codeplex.com/) library:

```js
var res = Enumerable.From([
  {date: new Date(), price: 10},
  {date: new Date(), price: 20},
  {date: new Date(2014, 15, 4), price: 30},
  {date: new Date(2014, 15, 4), price: 40},
  {date: new Date(2014, 15, 4), price: 50}
]).GroupBy("$.date.getMonth() + 1", null, function (key, gr) {
     var temp = {
           month: key,
           totalPrice: gr.Sum("$.price")
     };
     console.log(temp);
     return temp;
}).ToArray();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://neue.cc/linq.min.js"></script>
```